# java.lang.IllegelStateException while most of video is black

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm using this example [ExtractMpegFramesTest.java](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/ExtractMpegFramesTest_egl14.java.txt) in order to extract video frame by frame.

First I record video from device camera and then I do image manipulation on each frame.

The code works fine for most of the videos, But in example, if I put the device of the table and then recording it (That's mean that the video looks black and gray colors) the application crashed and this is what I've got in the log file

```
java.lang.IllegelStateException
```

After debugging the code I found that the application goes to  the default case in this "Switch"

```
int outIndex = decoder.dequeueOutputBuffer( info, 10000  );
          Log.v("My Error", "outIndex = " + outIndex);
          switch ( outIndex ) {
          case MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED:
             Log.d( TAG, "INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED" );
             outputBuffers = decoder.getOutputBuffers();
             break;
          case MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED:
             Log.d( TAG, "New format " + decoder.getOutputFormat() );
             break;
          case MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER:
             Log.d( TAG, "dequeueOutputBuffer timed out!" );
             break;
          default:
             ByteBuffer buffer = outputBuffers[outIndex];
             Log.v( TAG, "We can't use this buffer but render it due to the API limit, " + buffer );
```

Do someone know why it caused?

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace

Comment: Sorry for the newbie question, but how can I stop the log after the error occur? the stack was full after a sec with the "java.lang..." exception.

Comment: Look at the logcat. You should find it there

Comment: The log cat get full too fast with one error, what I've written

Comment: The problem is that it reach to the end of the stream too early. I get to this line ** decoder.queueInputBuffer( inIndex, 0, 0, 0, MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM );** after ~500 frames, when the video is more than 1 minute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the answer for this question!

As I figured out, the problem was that the video reaching to the end of the streaming too fast.

The cause of this issue is the black frames.
when there are a lot of black frames, the rate increased and reach to the end of the file faster.

One solution for this, is to record longer video.

Another question if so, is there another option to know what is the frame rate and if it's too fast then stop the extraction?